# Do successful researchers have some "trick" in common that leads to their success?

Tags: research-process

Is there some sort of secret trait or skill I can develop to become a more successful researcher?

Comment: How do you define success?

Comment: No. Unless you consider having good ideas, strong work ethics, and the luck to be at the right place at the right time to be secret traits or skills.

Comment: Why should there be one? And if there was one, how would it remain secret?

Comment: I have voted to close this question, because it's too broad (there is obviously no single "trick", so answers are going to offer all kinds of general advice), and opinion-based (answers are going to be very subjective).

Comment: Mate I have no idea how I am getting where I am getting. Just keep going.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any trick. But, I started to get better at my research, by trying to understand and replicate what people far more successful than me were doing.

The number one thing is to start collaborating with the successful people. But, that's not easy since most want to collaborate with them. As a student or postdoc you can try to apply to vacant positions in their groups. As a senior researcher, your best bet are successful people who are young and will be likely influent in their communities in a few years.

Once you get working with these successful people, you need to keep up, or you'll fall behind. So you have to be prepared to put in the hours and the work that's needed.

Then you start paying attention to how your successful collaborators actually work: some organize themselves very well, some know how to get most out of the strengths of their group's members, some are good at politics, at grant writing, and some are good when it comes to choosing and solving research problems. You need to see what others do better then you and understand why.

But, as someone who has asked many successful colleagues this exact question, don't expect a recipe type of answer. Each of us has their own recipe for success and very few of us know how we developed it. You need to look at others and select only what works for you.

A second thought about success is that people who choose hard and important problems to solve and come at them with everything they've got (including collaborators), become successful, but only after they learn to be more realistic about what can be actually solved within their means. Setting out to solve an important problem and having a degree of success is the surefire way to start collaborating with successful researchers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by success.

If you seem to have trouble converting ideas into publications and gaining visibility - and given that you want to achieve just that - become more "product-oriented". To do more research, you would need more resources; that ultimately boils down to securing funding and having enough time for work. To get said funding, you presumably would need prestigious publications, so in this mindset, producing actually great research matters less than producing lots of things in agreeable quality. As soon as your work passes a certain threshold, promote it heavily, make others fill the gaps, salami publish... All these practices are not particularly popular and ethically dubious, but if you want to run your research as a business, they are a way to go.

If you are aiming for something more balanced and harmonious instead, still consider that you need to communicate your results, and have mid- and long-term goals reasonably clear to you. Make sure to stay well-connected: this is probably the only inhibitor preventing you from ending up being considered one of the top experts in your field if you just work long and hard enough.

Good work ethic, good networking, clear goals. The rest is just talent and luck.